# ABAP check delivery header

Tags: abap

Is there a way to check document changes in the header of a delivery?

I tried it with the `CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_HEADERS`.

Like this:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_HEADERS'
  EXPORTING
    objectclass    = 'LIEFERUNG'
    objectid       = l_cdobjid
    date_of_change = p_datfr
    time_of_change = p_timfr
    date_until     = p_datto
    time_until     = p_timto
    username       = ''
  TABLES
    i_cdhdr        = lt_cdhdr
  EXCEPTIONS
    OTHERS         = 4.
```

Greetings

Comment: Basically you are on the right track, this FM reads the header of the change documents (table CDHDR). The question is, how you call the FM, with wchich parameters?

Comment: Ok, I changed the question that you can see how I did it.

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai I expexting if I change the field "BOLNR" (delivery header->shipment->BillOfLad) that the `CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_HEADERS` FM recognizes this.

Comment: Seems to be OK (objectid has to be delivery number with leading zeros). The actual field changes will be in table CDPOS, you can check FM CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_POSITIONS for that.

Comment: You can double check it: in transaction VL03N display the delivery and in Menu: Environment / Changes. You can display what is stored in the system after you changed the field BOLNR. I believe SAP will also you use these FMs (see above) for reading the changes, so you can set breakpoints into them and see with what parameters are they called.

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai  Thank you very much for your answers. How I understand the FM `CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_POSITIONS` does only check the results which I got our of the `CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_HEADERS` is that right?

Comment: Yes, ..._HEADERS reads table CDHDR, ..._POSITIONS reads table CDPOS